# Trying to get property of non-object in view - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

There are lot of issues with this same topic but in my code, i don't see my error to be getting

> > Trying to get property of non-object

My models also seems alright. Could the issue results from my database relation?

**Parents**

```
  public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('parents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); 

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Child**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('parent_phone')->references('phone')->on('parents')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); 
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**ChildModel**

```
public function parents(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class, 'parent_phone');
  }
```

**View**

```
 @foreach ($item->parents as $parent)
        <td>{{ $parent->child }} <br/>
        <small>{{ $parent->created_at }}</small>
        <br>
        <small>{{ $parent->parents->name }}</small>

        </td>
      @endforeach
```

Comment: How are you passing `$item` to the view? Should there a loop for `$items`, or are you passing a single `$item`? Etc etc. Also, see if you can find the full error (file/line) and include that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship is not quite right.

Because your foreign key (`parent_phone`) is not referencing the primary key (`id`) on the `parents` table, you need to specify the name of the field on `parents` that it references. This is done using the third parameter to the `belongsTo()` method. Your relationship should look like:

```
public function parents(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class, 'parent_phone', 'phone');
}
```

You can read more about [Eloquent relationships in the documentation here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Even after correcting the relationship, your view may still return this error because of this line:

```
{{ $parent->parents->name }}
```

If your `parent` record does not have a `parent` record, you will be attempting to access `->name` on `null`, and that'll throw the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. worked pefectly